# Does Stylus support arrays of variables?

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

I can't find in [the docs](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/variables.html) an example of using arrays as variables. It would be obvious though to have arrays support so I suspect I should search for that in a different way.

I have found lists, but not sure if these are intended for the same or similar purpose as arrays and couldn't find syntax and examples.

I have a list of colors

```
- cards_colors = #E0137E #8431BF #2388C4 #FED462 #EC633B #B3CF32 #2388C4 #EA8527
```

And I want to assign each color to a respective element in a loop, similar to this:

```
    for num in (0..10)
        &.card-{num}
            background cards_colors[{num}]
```

Comment: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/iteration.html

Answer (score 6):

using a list works for me:

```
cards_colors = ( #E0137E #8431BF #2388C4 )

for num in (0..2)
  .card-{num}
    background cards_colors[num]
```

see demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IeiEw

Answer (score 2):

Stylus does support arrays, but it's hard to find in their [documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/), even after they revamped it

```
$arrayName = value0, value1, value2
$arrayName[1] //value1
```

Answer (score 1):

With using range()

```
cards_colors = ( #E0137E #8431BF #2388C4 )

for num in range(0,(length(cards_colors) - 1))
  .card-{num}
    background cards_colors[num]
```