# Generating selectors with Stylus loop

Tags: loops, stylus

In Stylus, I am trying to generate `:nth-of-type()` selectors based on a color array. This is actually my first time with arrays in stylus so I am a bit perplexed as per the semicolon- and bracket-free syntax I am seeing in [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438331/does-stylus-support-arrays-of-variables).

The goal is to have an equivalent of the following:

```
.chart {
  li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;

    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      background-color: #FFE3A9;
      span {
        background-color: #FFCC66;
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      background-color: #FCCCA2;
      span {
        background-color: #F79850;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My attempt:

```
bg_colors = (#FFEDA9 #FDCCA2)
fill_colors = (#FFCD66 #FD9850)

.chart {
  li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;

    for num in range(0, 1)
      &:nth-of-type({num})
        background-color: bg_colors[num]
        span
          background-color: fill_colors[num]
  }
}
```

I am getting compilation errors from an unexpected `}` (angular cli) so I am wondering where my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410889/stylus-iteration-interpolation-with-nth-of-type

Comment: Even if a duplicate, the answer there does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So, this question *is* unique to [the duplicate I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410889/stylus-iteration-interpolation-with-nth-of-type) - mainly because there are 2 arrays used in the loop. You may want to rename the question for future searches.

**First off**, it took me a long time to realise I needed to take error messages seriously. In your case - it's telling you *there are brackets* - and there shouldn't be - so they are unexpected. Remove them. Stylus syntax is mostly just like SCSS - all you have to do is type less things - and ensure that your indents are perfect. The indents replace the brackets in clarifying the rules' beginning and end. Remove ALL brackets - and semicolons. *(Side note - use $var for variables / they are likely to be required later - also - `:` used to be an option - they are also going to be required)

**Second**, I'm guessing that this `for` loop is like an each loop in Javascript, so you can get `currentvalue, currentIndex, fullArray` parameters out with a comma separated list. (I'm not 100% on that)

`for fillColor, currentIndex in $fillColorArray`

This would allow you to access the color and its index as these placeholders.

Here is alive example: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/64c6791116c3a180cb196610f9962f17/  - you can choose to view the compiled CSS in the stylus pane's little arrow icon.

markup

```
<ul class="chart-list one">
    <li class="chart">
        <span>Chart 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="chart">
        <span>Chart 2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="chart">
        <span>Chart 3</span>
    </li>
    <li class="chart">
        <span>Chart 4</span>
    </li>
</ul>

...
```

You can do this a few ways - depending on the application. Here is an example with 2 loops - and another with a single loop.

stylus

```
$fillColorArray = (#f06 pink)
$textColorArray = (white #f06)

remove-list-styles()
    list-style: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.chart-list
    remove-list-styles()
    margin-bottom: 2rem
    background: lightgray
    .chart
        padding: 1rem

.chart-list.one
    //
    .chart
        //
        for fillColor, currentIndex in $fillColorArray
            &:nth-of-type({currentIndex + 1})
                background: fillColor
        for textColor, currentIndex in $textColorArray
            &:nth-of-type({currentIndex + 1})
                span
                    color: textColor

.chart-list.two
    //
    .chart
        //
        for fillColor, currentIndex in $fillColorArray
            &:nth-of-type({currentIndex + 1})
                background: fillColor
                span
                    color: $textColorArray[currentIndex]

// &:nth-of-type( 2n + {currentIndex + 1})
// if you want it to repeat at those intervals
.chart-list.three
    //
    .chart
        //
        for fillColor, currentIndex in $fillColorArray
            &:nth-of-type( 2n + {currentIndex + 1})
                background: fillColor
                span
                    color: $textColorArray[currentIndex]
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed example, but this sort of confirms @panya 's answer that one cannot mix bracket style notation (which I use all over my code) with loops. So, in order to be able to use loops I would have to convert my .styl file to indent-based.

Comment: Yes. Stylus files don't use brackets. @panya confirms that the error you received was correct - and I'm confirming that your expectations are possible.

Comment: Also - one more note - as @payna implies: you CAN use brackets in your stylus - but you have to use them for the entire rule. Sometimes I get a nasty bit of CSS from a 3rd party, and instead of rewriting it, I just let it be it's normal CSS with brackets and it's totally fine. Just don't mix them up in the same block.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix indent-style and brackets-style inside nested blocks. When Stylus sees a bracket-style block its assume that all nested blocks inside the block will be with brackets too.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: It's an answer to the question "I am wondering where my syntax is wrong"